# Android how do I get the position of a row in an ListView from an onClickHandler()

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a view that has a custom ArrayAdapter as a ListAdapter.
Customer is a Poco:

```
public class Customer {
    public String LastName;
    public boolean IsActive;
}
```

What works: I have sucesfully bound my ArrayList to my ListView, the LastName is displayed as a text and the CheckBox is checked or not (depending on IsActive) but now I want to update the ArrayList everytime the checkbox is checked but I can't access the position in the OnClickListener:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Customer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items) {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        if (null == convertView) {
            row =  mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, null);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        ctv.setText(getItem(position).LastName);
        ctv.setChecked(getItem(position).IsChecked);

        ctv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v;
                ctv.toggle();

                // this does not work because I don't have the position
                getItem(position).IsChecked = (ctv).isChecked();

            }

        });

        return row;
    }

});
```

I thought about inheriting from CheckedTextBox and adding a custom property `setPosition/getPosition` to store the position for later use or even add a reference to the related object but I suppose there is an existing solution I can't find atm.

Comment: You could also store the position in the checkedtextview tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle the click not by the row, but by the ListActivity

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

that gives you everything you need. Override the method in your ListActivity.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the ListView to give it an onItemClickListener and pass it an AdapterView which would look like that :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // here you have th view, the position, everything you need to have fun ;=)
    //you can acces the content of your adapter here with :   
    mAdapter.getItem(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 works, too. But I chosse Warrens answer because using the override saves me a line of code because I don't need to do `findViewById(...)` to get my ListView.
And his answer was a whole second earlier :D

Comment: That's fine for me, but you will see that if you want to do other things to your ListView, you will have to call it anyway. Good luck